# Convert Access application from MDB (2000) to ACCDB (2007/2010) using Python

Tags: python, database, ms-access

I am trying to convert `MS Access` database from version `2000` to `2007` or `2010`. I have to achieve this using `Python`.

If I install `MS Access 2007` or `MS Access 2010`, it works. But I want to do this without installing these versions of `MS Access`. I tried installing `MS Access 2010 Runtime`, but not working.

I have tried `pypyodbc` module but it is only working for `mdb` database. I have also tried following with `win32com.client.Dispatch()`:

```
    Access.Application (ConvertAccessProject)
    JRO.JetEngine (CompactDatabase)
    DAO.DBEngine (CompactDatabase)
```

None of above is working.

I searched a lot on the internet but did not find any solution till now. Let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: Are you talking about converting just data tables, or are you looking to convert an entire Access application with forms, reports, macros, module code, etc.?

Comment: @GordThompson, I am looking to convert entire Access application

Comment: @GordThompson, what is the possible way to convert just data tables?

Answer (score 1):

> If I install MS Access 2007 or MS Access 2010, it works. But I want to [convert an entire Access application from Access 2000 to Access 2007 or Access 2010] without installing these versions of MS Access. I tried installing MS Access 2010 Runtime, but not working.

Your objective is impossible to achieve. In order to convert an entire Access application (with forms, reports, module code, etc.) from Access 2000 to Access 2007 or Access 2010 you must have a full version of Access 2007 or Access 2010 installed because that's where the conversion code is.

Comment: ok. Is there any possible way to convert only data tables? as you asked in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

I have only had troubles with Python, but it could be this:

```
Access.Application.ConvertAccessProject sourcefile, targetfile, acFileFormatAccess2007
```

Or, as the constant probably is unknown to P:

```
Access.Application.ConvertAccessProject sourcefile, targetfile, 12
```

Perhaps you need to be a bit more explicit:

```
ap = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
ap.ConvertAccessProject(s, t, 12)
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working. If I install `MS Access 2007`, then this works. But I want this without installing `MS Access`. OR it should work with `MS Access 2010 Runtime`.

Comment: This is `Python` code: `win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application").ConvertAccessProject(s, d, 12)`... But not working..

Comment: I tried what you suggested in EDIT, but not working :(

Comment: Gord is right. You call Access, so you need Access, even though (I guess) you only converts tables. Don't know if a runtime install will do.